# convert bash `ls` output to json array

Tags: linux, json, bash, ubuntu, sh

Is it possible to use a bash script to format the output of the `ls` to a json array? To be valid json, all names of the dirs and files need to be wrapped in double quotes, seperated by a comma, and the entire thing needs to be wrapped in square brackets. I.e. convert:

```
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ls
foo.txt bar baz
```

to

```
[ "foo.txt", "bar", "baz" ]
```

edit: I strongly prefer something that works across all my Linux servers; hence rather not depend on python, but have a pure bash solution.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. If you are worried about python not being available, use perl. It should be on almost all linux servers.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this via the json manipulation tool jq? http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: Now there's [jc](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc) from [@Kelly Brazil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12303989/kelly-brazil), which is actually nice.    

Strange that [his reply got deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646499/537554).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use perl as the encoder; it's guaranteed to be non-buggy, is everywhere, and with pipes, it's still reasonably clean:

```
ls | perl -e 'use JSON; @in=grep(s/\n$//, <>); print encode_json(\@in)."\n";'
```

Comment: **-1**.  This suffers from the classic [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem.  Better to do it in a for loop and avoid the pipe entirely.  See Glenn Jackman's answer for the correct approach.

Comment: " it's guaranteed to be non-buggy, is everywhere".... except for you have to install another module.. So its not everywhere as such.. Sorry but ideal solutions involve already available components

Comment: Confirmed, the module is not installed on Fedora 35 using the default config.
`Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (you may need to install the JSON module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.30 /usr/local/share/perl5/5.30 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.`

# +1 to the jq answer and simple to install on Fedora
`sudo dnf -y install jq`

Answer (score 34):

If you know that no filename contains newlines, use jq:

`ls | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")[:-1]'`

Short explanation of the flags to jq:

- `-R` treats the input as string instead of JSON
- `-s` joins all lines into an array
- `-c` creates a compact output
- `[:-1]` removes the last empty string in the output array

This requires version 1.4 or later of jq. Try this if it doesn't work for you:

`ls | jq -R '[.]' | jq -s -c 'add'`

Comment: error: split is not defined
split("\n")
^^^^^
1 compile error

Comment: I have tried both `ls | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")'` and `ls | jq -R '[.]' | jq -s -c 'add'`. The former is having an extra empty string "" added into the array. So the latter is a better solution.

Comment: This can be simplified to `ls | jq --raw-input | jq --slurp --compact-output`.
Or if you prefer the short syntax: `ls | jq -R | jq -s -c`

Answer (score 31):

Yes, but the corner cases and Unicode handling will drive you up the wall. Better to delegate to a scripting language that supports it natively.

```
$ ls
あ  a  "a"  à  a b  私
$ python -c 'import os, json; print json.dumps(os.listdir("."))'
["\u00e0", "\"a\"", "\u79c1", "a b", "\u3042", "a"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but really prefer something that generally works on any Linux server; so I rather have a pure Bash solution.

Comment: 99.8% of the Linux servers out there have Python available; admittedly you may need to use simplejson though, for older versions of Python.

Comment: A server without python = Hell. You'll probably get a perl solution soon too.

Comment: Yeah not everyone has that. And I don't want to ask all users of my software to install additional repositories to be able to run a script.

Comment: So then provide links directly to the packages.

Answer (score 18):

Hello you can do that with sed and awk:

```
ls | awk ' BEGIN { ORS = ""; print "["; } { print "\/\@"$0"\/\@"; } END { print "]"; }' | sed "s^\"^\\\\\"^g;s^\/\@\/\@^\", \"^g;s^\/\@^\"^g"
```

EDIT: updated to solve the problem with `"` and spaces. I use `/@` as replacement pattern for `"`, since `/` is not a valid character for filename.

Comment: Note that this solution does not properly escape double-quotes which may be in the name, e.g. a file named `foo\"bar` comes out as `"foo"bar"` instead of `"foo\"bar"`.

Comment: also directories with a space in the name are problematic.

Comment: **-1**.  This also suffers from the classic [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly your awk and sed statements are doing? Specifically, the second print statement in your awk and the 3 sed statements. Here, `s^\/\@^\"^g`, I see that you're escaping the `/@` but I fail to see how you're inserting the commas in between all the entries piped from `ls`.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Linux machine already has python. all you have to do is:

```
python -c 'import os, json; print json.dumps(os.listdir("/yourdirectory"))'
```

This is for . directory , you can add any path.

Comment: Your answer seems to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10234470/817632

Comment: How would I change this to follow directories also?

Comment: you can do this for different directories using python -c 'import os, json; print json.dumps(os.listdir("/mydirectory/temp"))'

Comment: How do we handle this for only files?

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty easy.

```
$ cat ls2json.bash
#!/bin/bash
echo -n '['
for FILE in $(ls | sed -e 's/"/\\"/g')
do
echo -n \"${FILE}\",
done
echo -en \\b']'
```

then run:

```
$ ./ls2json.bash > json.out
```

but python would be even easier

```
import os
directory = '/some/dir'
ls = os.listdir(directory)
dirstring = str(ls)
print dirstring.replace("'",'"')
```

Comment: Could you add the comma that seperates two strings?

Comment: oh, yeah, forgot in translation, fixed, problem there is that there will be a trailing comma. hmm.

Comment: Well the tricky thing is that there should not be a comma after the last element, right before the ]

Comment: You need to set a variable `set FIRST=true`, and at the end of the loop, set it to `false`.  Output a comma before FILE when FIRST is false.

Comment: easy fix, echo -en \\b ']', added

Comment: Note that this solution does not properly escape double-quotes which may be in the name, e.g. a file named `foo\"bar` comes out as `"foo"bar"` instead of `"foo\"bar"`.

Comment: true, it would give you "Stupid"Filename.txt" in that case.  quick fix with sed.

Comment: **-1** for the the [Parsing LS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) problem.  I had hope when I saw the for loop, but this way misses the mark.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash line

```
echo '[' ; ls --format=commas|sed -e 's/^/\"/'|sed -e 's/,$/\",/'|sed -e 's/\([^,]\)$/\1\"\]/'|sed -e 's/, /\", \"/g'
```

Won't properly deal with `"`, `\` or some commas in the name of the file.  Also, if `ls` puts newlines between filenames, so will this.

Comment: Also won't deal with tabs, newlines or other control characters in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for a way to output a Linux folder / file tree to some JSON or XML file. Why not use this simple terminal command:

```
$ tree --dirsfirst --noreport -n -X -i -s -D -f -o my.xml
```

so, just the linux tree command, and config your own parameters. Here `-X` gives XML output! For me, that's OK, and i guess there's some script to convert XML to JSON ..

NOTE: I think [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90115/convert-output-of-tree-command-to-json-format/) covers the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant one-liner solution that doesn't rely on jq:

```
echo '[ "'"$(echo "$list" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/", "/g')"'" ]'
```

`$list` here is a newline-separated string.

Comment: There's a lot more escaping than this needed to transform all possible filenames into valid JSON. Filenames can contain tab characters; they can contain literal newlines; they can contain literal quotes; they can contain backslashes; etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu column (i.e. doesn't work on OSX)

```
ls -ldG * --time-style=long-iso | column -t -n "$PWD" -N mod,links,user,size,date,time,name -J
```

Output :

```
{
   "/home/pouet": [
      {"mod":"-rwxr-xr-x", "links":"1", "user":"pouet", "size":"21978", "date":"2022-08-12", "time":"11:47", "name":"file1"},
      {"mod":"-rw-r--r--", "links":"1", "user":"pouet", "size":"2634", "date":"2022-06-20", "time":"11:14", "name":"file2"}
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution using [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/):

```bash
ls | jq --raw-input | jq --slurp --compact-output
```

or if you prefer the shorter syntax:

```bash
ls | jq -R | jq -s -c
```

From the manual

https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq

> `--raw-input / -R`
>
> Don't parse the input as JSON. Instead, each line of text is passed to the filter as a string. If combined with --slurp, then the entire input is passed to the filter as a single long string.

> `--slurp / -s`
>
> Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.

> `--compact-output / -c`
>
> By default, jq pretty-prints JSON output. Using this option will result in more compact output by instead putting each JSON object on a single line.

Answer (score -1):

Personnaly, I would code script that would run the command ls, send the output to a file of you choice while parsing the output to make format it to a valid JSON format.

I'm sure that a simple Bash file will do the work.

[Bash ouput](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/output-redirection-with-bash/)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use a python script like this?

```
myOutput = subprocess.check_output["ls"]
output = ["+str(e)+" for e in myOutput]
return output
```

I didn't check if it works, but you can find the specification [here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Answer (score -3):

Don't use bash, use a scripting language. Untested perl example:

```
use JSON;
my @ls_output = `ls`; ## probably better to use a perl module to do this, like DirHandle
print encode_json( @ls_output );
```