# Convert bash `ls` output to json array and print working directory to every element in the JSON array

Tags: python, json, bash, jq

I would like to print my output of the ls command as a JSON array with the current working directory as the prefix for every element in the array.

I managed to find another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234327/convert-bash-ls-output-to-json-array) which helped me sort the first part out of my problem, but would appreciate some help with the prefix part.

Lets say I have the following directory and file structure:

```
 Docs (Directory)
 |
 +-- Random file 1
 |    
 +-- Readme (Working Directory)
 |  |  
 |  +-- Readme.md
 |  +-- Readyou.md
```

When I execute the following command in the Readme Directory (**taken from the thread I linked to earlier**):

```
python -c 'import os, json; print json.dumps(os.listdir("."))'
```

I get the following output:

```
["Readme.md", "Readyou.md"]
```

What I would like to achieve is the structure above, **BUT** with the working directory as the prefix for every element in the array.

```
["Readme/Readme.md", "Readme/Readyou.md"]
```

Is this something that can managed pretty straightforward in bash?

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
(cd .. && find Readme -print0) | jq -sR 'split("\u0000")[1:]'
```

Comment: Would have upvoted if I could. Worked pretty smooth.

Comment: @Nael you should be able to accept the answer even if you can't upvote them yet; it gives even more reputation! Check [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have troubles doing so.