# List up my apps installable with brew-cask

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I want to know which of my apps are available to install with `brew cask` command.
How can I do it?

---

**Specification**
What I want to do is to extract apps that are also available on brew-cask from all apps in `/Applications` and list up their package-names.

```
# /Applications
Alfred 4.app
App Store.app
AppCleaner.app
Automator.app
Be Focused Pro.app
BetterTouchTool.app
Bitdefender
Bluetooth Explorer.app
Books.app
Calculator.app
Calendar.app
CheatSheet.app
Chess.app
Clipy.app
...
```

```
# package names of apps available on brew-cask
alfred
appcleaner
bettertouchtool
calibre
cheatsheet
clip
...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Perhaps you're trying to view a list of *cask apps you have **already** installed, * or which currently installed apps can be *upgraded?*

Comment: All apps are manually installed (I knew brew-cask today). I want to know which of them are also available from brew-cask.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930492/list-of-installable-homebrew-casks) is useful, it sounds similar to what you're trying to do

Comment: @solzard I added an answer, I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using [Homebrew’s JSON API](https://formulae.brew.sh/docs/api/) as well as some [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) magic (`brew install jq`).

1. Assuming none of your `.app` filenames contain a newline (very unlikely), you can get the list as a JSON array with [a command combining `ls` and `jq`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32354503/735926). However since we’ll use that list as a lookup it’s better to create an object instead:

   ```sh
   ls /Applications \
   | \grep '\.app$' \
   | jq -Rsc 'split("\n")[:-1]|map({(.):1})|add'
   ```

   This creates an object with each app as a key and `1` as a value (the value has no importance here). It outputs something like:

   ```json
   {"1Password 7.app":1,"Amphetamine.app":1, "Firefox.app":1, …}
   ```
2. You can list all 3,500+ installable casks using `brew search --casks`. In order to get a JSON describing one or more cask(s), including the `.app` they install, you can use `brew cask info --json=v1 <cask> …`.

   Combining these two, we can get a huge JSON describing all installable casks with:

   ```sh
   brew search --casks '' \
   | xargs brew info --cask --json=v2 \
   > allcasks.json
   ```

   This command takes ~10s on my machine so saving it in a file is a good idea.
3. We can now filter this list to extract only the casks that install `.app`s from our earlier list:

   ```sh
   cat allcasks.json \
   | jq -r --argjson list '{…the list…}' '.[]|.[]|(.artifacts|map(.[]?|select(type=="string")|select(in($list)))|first) as $app|select($app)|"\(.token): \($app)"'
   ```

   Replace `{…the list…}` with the object we created earlier.

   This prints something like:

   ```
   1password: 1Password 7.app
   firefox: Firefox.app
   google-chrome: Google Chrome.app
   …
   ```

---

If you feel adventurous, here is a one-liner that does all these commands at once:

```sh
brew search --casks '' \
|xargs brew info --cask --json=v2 \
|jq -r --argjson l "$(ls /Applications|\grep '\.app$'|jq -Rsc 'split("\n")[:-1]|map({(.):1})|add')" '.[]|.[]|(.artifacts|map(.[]?|select(type=="string")|select(in($l)))|first) as $a|select($a)|"\(.token): \($a)"'
```

---

Breakdown of the `jq` command:

```
.[] # flatten the list
 |  # then for each element:
 .[] # flatten the list
 |  # then for each element:
   ( # take its artifacts
     .artifacts
      # then for each one of them
      | map(
         # take only arrays
         .[]?
         # select their string elements
         | select(type=="string")
         # that are also in the list
         | select(in($list)
       )
   )
   # take the first matching artifact
   | first)
   # and store it in $app
   as $app
 # then take only the elements with a non-empty $app
 | select($app)
 # and print their name (.token) and the app ($app)
 |"\(.token): \($app)"
```

Comment: Looks like this no longer works with Homebrew `>=3.0.0` because the `brew cask` command no longer exists. Also, `brew info --cask` only accepts `v2` for the `json` flag, which seemingly does not work with the provided `jq` command: `$ brew search --casks | xargs brew info --cask --json=v2 > allcasks.json` and then `cat allcasks.json | jq -r --argjson list '{[…]}' '.[]|(.artifacts|map(.[]?|select(type=="string")|select(in($list)))|first) as $app|select($app)|"\(.token): \($app)"'` fails with `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "artifacts"`.

Comment: Adding another ".[]" after the first one fixes the issue. The jq query becomes: `'.[]|.[]|(.artifacts|map(.[]?|select(type=="string")|select(in($list)))|first) as $app|select($app)|"\(.token): \($app)"'`

Comment: Just to clarify, the new command for getting the cask list is: `brew search --casks '' | xargs brew info --cask --json=v2 > allcasks.json`

Comment: @aboy021 could you edit the response to fix these issues? This is fresher in your mind than in mine ;)

Comment: I managed to get the following "one liner" working:
```brew search --casks --desc '' | sed -n -e 's/:.*$//p' | xargs brew info --cask --json=v2 | jq -r --argjson list "$(ls /Applications | \grep '\.app$' | jq -Rsc 'split("\n")[:-1]|map({(.):1})|add')" '.[]|.[]|(.artifacts|map(.[]?|select(type=="string")|select(in($list)))|first) as $app|select($app)|"\(.token): \($app)"' > matchingCasks.json```
I had to add the '--desc' flag to get around an odd: "Error: Cask '==>' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists." and the 'sed' was added to remove the unnecessary tacked on description.

Answer (score 1):

I need to do some minor modification to make this one liner work on my Mac.

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.0.28-5-g9f9ae1e
macOS: 13.4.1-x86_64
```

```
brew search --casks --desc '' --eval-all | sed -n -e 's/:.*$//p' | xargs brew info --cask --json=v2 | jq -r --argjson list "$(ls /Applications | \grep '\.app$' | jq -Rsc 'split("\n")[:-1]|map({(.):1})|add')" '.[]|.[]|(.artifacts|.[]|map(.[]?|select(type=="string")|select(in($list)))|first) as $app|select($app)|"\(.token): \($app)"' > matchingCasks.json
```

Comment: Still works in Feb 2024.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `brew search` on your terminal, like theses examples :

- `brew search vlc`
- `brew search mamp`
- `brew search slack`
- ...etc

You will get the available brew casks corresponding your search and you can install it with `brew cask install mamp` (replace `mamp` with your own app)

You can also go on this page https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/ to see all available casks.

If you app is already installed, you need to use `brew cask install --force mamp` to force the reinstallation and link your app already installed.

For more explanations, you can go here https://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Homebrew/Cask.html.